# Click em botão não funciona

Tags: html, jquery

Não estou conseguindo fazer o botão Remover funcionar de jeito nenhum. Eu gero ele dinamicamente através do jquery, mas na hora de remover o botão não da resposta alguma. Nem a mensagem do console aparece...

```js
var pares = 0;

$("#codigo_barras").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which===13){
      var codigo = $(this).val();
      var linha = $("<div>").addClass("row p-1 bordaCodigo");
      var colunaCodigo = $("<div>").addClass("col-sm-2").text(codigo);
      var botaoRemover = $("<button>").addClass("remover btn btn-danger").append("<span class='fa fa-times'>X</span>");
      var colunaRemover = $("<div>").addClass("col-sm-1");
      colunaRemover.append(botaoRemover);
      linha.append(colunaRemover);
      linha.append(colunaCodigo);
      $(".codigos").append(linha);

      pares++;
      $(".pares").text(pares);
    }   
});

$(".remover").on("click",function(){
  console.log("teste");
  var linha = $(this).parent().parent();
  linha.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="codigo_barras">
<div class="codigos"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que quando o código

```js
$(".remover").on("click",function(){
  console.log("teste");
  var linha = $(this).parent().parent();
  linha.remove();
});
```

É executado nenhum elemento `.remover` existe no DOM e, assim, nenhum deles receberá o evento *click*. Ao invés disso, adicione o evento no elemento pai e verifique se o evento foi gerado a partir de um `.remover` filho.

```js
$(".codigos").on("click", ".remover", function(){
  console.log("teste");
  var linha = $(this).parent().parent();
  linha.remove();
});
```

Assim o evento ficará associado ao elemento `.codigos`, que já existe no DOM, mas será disparado apenas quando partir de um filho `.remover`.

```js
var pares = 0;

$("#codigo_barras").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which===13){
      var codigo = $(this).val();
      var linha = $("<div>").addClass("row p-1 bordaCodigo");
      var colunaCodigo = $("<div>").addClass("col-sm-2").text(codigo);
      var botaoRemover = $("<button>").addClass("remover btn btn-danger").append("<span class='fa fa-times'>X</span>");
      var colunaRemover = $("<div>").addClass("col-sm-1");
      colunaRemover.append(botaoRemover);
      linha.append(colunaRemover);
      linha.append(colunaCodigo);
      $(".codigos").append(linha);

      pares++;
      $(".pares").text(pares);
    }   
});

$(".codigos").on("click", ".remover", function(){
  console.log("teste");
  var linha = $(this).parent().parent();
  linha.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Digite um <input placeholder="Código de Barras" id="codigo_barras"> e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>
<div class="codigos"></div>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Valeu amigo.